# $\{X \mid \text{trace}(X)=c\}$ is a hyperplane?

Tags: matrices, geometry, convex-analysis

A hyperplane is a set of the form:

$$\{x\in \mathbf{R}^n \ \ \mid \ \ a^Tx=b, a\in \mathbf{R}^n\}$$

This definition is quite intuitive.

However, I am reading some books or paper and they say

[Hyperplane: $\text{trace}(X)=1$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCl8z.png)

with a picture to illustrate it:

[Picture of hyperplane: $\text{trace}(X)=1$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UKJg.png)

How can I understand such hyperplane by the intuitive form above or is there any more general definition of hyperplane?
(By LMI?)

Comment: Note that a hyperplane is in general any subspace of a vector space given by a linear equation: $\sum a_i x_i = b$. Now in the $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$-dimensional vector space of $n\times n$ matrices, $b=\mathrm{trace}(X)=\sum x_{ii}$ is indeed such equation. Your "vector" (not matrix) $a$ here is given via $a_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: Trace is a linear form on $\mathcal M_n(\mathbf R)=\mathbf R^{\color{red}{n\times n}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trace is a linear functional $\;M_n(\Bbb R)\to\Bbb R\;$ , thus

$$H:=\left\{A\in M_n(\Bbb R)\;/\;tr.(A)=0\right\}=\ker\text{ tr.}$$

is a hyperlane in $\;M_n(\Bbb R)\;$ , meaning: a maximal proper subspace in $\;M_n(\Bbb R)\;$, and then what you call a hyperplane is just a translation by $\;1\;$ of the above *actual* hyperplane. It though is **not** a subspace.

Comment: You seem to be implying that $\mathrm{tr} = 1$ does not define an "actual" hyperplane because it does not contain the origin. But a hyperplane does not have to be a subspace.

Comment: The translation (shift) of a (vectorial) hyperplane is called [affine hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane#Affine_hyperplanes) and we may say just hyperplane for brevity.

Comment: @Rahul Thank you. I guess that depends on the usage of the words, just as user's comment shows